# How do i add (android and apple) files on mobile pygame Replit

Tags: file, replit

I was looking for a way to code on the go and I found replit which has many programming languages, the one I found and I use is pygame. Everything (so far) has been working fine except I don’t know how to load my (both android and apple) files in to the system so I can easily upload sprites or anything else

Because this is more of a technical problem I haven’t been able to do anything other then ask the community but they were no responses.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I said “bot” I can’t